# how to conditionally pass a message to a specific next stage (among other stages)?

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe, akka-stream

Consider a simple scenario when depending on some attribute of the message passing through, I want it to be processed by a specific next stage and continue on.

```
[Source[ActionMessage]] ~> [Flow[ActionMessage, EnrichedActionMessage]] 
~> (eAM: EnrichedActionMessage => eAM.actionType match {
      case ActionA => eAM ~> Flow[EnrichedActionMessage, ReactionA] ~> Sink[ReactionA]
      case ActionB => eAM ~> Flow[EnrichedActionMessage, ReactionB] ~> Sink[ReactionB]
      case ActionC => eAM ~> Flow[EnrichedActionMessage, ReactionC] ~> Sink[ReactionC]
    })
```

how do I achieve the conditional routing to the stage graph stage ?

Comment: Try creating a flow graph that uses a broadcast to fan out to 3 parallel forks.  Each fork will then have a filter step to filter down to the right type for that fork before going to a sink for that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on `akka-stream` version `2.4.2-RC1`. The API can be slightly different in other versions. The dependency can be consumed by [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/):

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.2-RC1"
```

---

Use a `Partition` component:

```
val shape = GraphDSL.create() { implicit b ⇒
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val first = b.add(Sink.foreach[Int](elem ⇒ println("first:\t" + elem)))
  val second = b.add(Sink.foreach[Int](elem ⇒ println("second:\t" + elem)))
  val third = b.add(Sink.foreach[Int](elem ⇒ println("third:\t" + elem)))
  val p = b.add(Partition[Int](3, elem ⇒ elem match {
    case 0                ⇒ 0
    case elem if elem < 0 ⇒ 1
    case elem if elem > 0 ⇒ 2
  }))

  p ~> first
  p ~> second
  p ~> third

  SinkShape(p.in)
}
Source(List(0, 1, 2, -1, 1, -5, 0)).to(shape).run()

/*
Output:
first: 0
third: 1
third: 2
second: -1
third: 1
second: -5
first: 0
*/
```

Instead of the `SinkShape` you can also return a `new FanOutShape3(p.in, p.out(0), p.out(1), p.out(2))` if you wish to do any processing of the elements at a later point.

Comment: using partition, is causing an issue wherein it doesn't send currently processed message to downstream component until some more messages have been pushed in from source into partition.

Comment: @theGhost I don't understand what you mean, every element that the partition receives will immediately be sent to one of the sinks.

Comment: ok. we found, streams materializer `autofuse` is enabled by default; causing a weird behavior of not propagating the chain of pull across the wired stages. disabling autofuse solved it.
Partition was infact working just fine.